# Tomcat Jersey 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet, http-status-code-404, jersey

Пытаюсь сделать REST API, используя Tomcat, но получаю на любой запрос - 404.

Отправляю такие запросы:

- POST `http://localhost:8764/rest/users/get`
- GET  `http://localhost:8764/rest/users`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело. Буду рад любым советам.

**`pom.xml`:**

```xml
    <properties>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
        <jersey.version>1.19.4</jersey.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>endpoints</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**`UserEndpoint.java`:**

```java
package endpoints;
@Path("/users")
public class UserEndpoint {

@GET
@Path("/")
public String users() {
    return "USER PAGE";
}

@POST
@Path("get")
public String getUsers() {
    return "USER";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Название сервлета не должно содержать пробелы

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST_Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>endpoints</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST_Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Убрал пробелы, но это не помогло(

Comment: В смысле, как не помогло?

Comment: Так же получаю 404 на запросы.
Сейчас обнаружил в логах запуска томката исключение:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\xampp\tomcat\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Возможно дело в нем.

Comment: Переустанивите Tomcat без native библиотек.

Comment: Что подразумевается под нативными библиотеками ?
Томкат у меня был в xampp, скачал его еще с оф.сайта - не помогло.

Comment: xampp надо удалить, вместе с томкэтом и установить новый tomcat. нативный означает исполняемый код.

Comment: Так я скачивал обычный томкат вот отсюда: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi из группы Core

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, в идее, в конфигурации Томкат-сервера, во вкладке Deployment я добавил вместо webapp варник с контекстом "/" и все заработало.